# How to select first 4 child tags from xml in mule

Tags: xml, xpath, mule

My requirement is to capture first 4 child xml tags in payload which is received from WS consumer.
Below is the response from WS consumer

```
<root>
 <client>
   <name>abc<name>
   <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
   <name>def<name>
   <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
   <name>ghi<name>
   <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
    <name>jkl<name>
    <status>failed</status>
 </client>
 <client>
    <name>mno<name>
    <status>success</status>
 </client>
 ......
 ......
 ......
</root>
```

Now i have to select only first 4 child tags in payload under root tag.

which looks like below.

```
<root>
 <client>
  <name>abc<name>
  <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
  <name>def<name>
  <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
  <name>ghi<name>
  <status>success</status>
 </client>
 <client>
  <name>jkl<name>
  <status>failed</status>
 </client>
</root>
```

Comment: `//client[position()<=4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following in dataweave.

```
root: payload.root.*client[0..3]
```

Keep the output content as application/xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use Mule [XSLT](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/xslt-transformer) transformer and do it in a simple way as follows:-

```
   <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="testxmlFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer doc:name="DOM to XML"/>
        <logger message="input xml:- #[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <mulexml:xslt-transformer xsl-file="response.xsl" maxIdleTransformers="2" maxActiveTransformers="5" doc:name="XSLT" mimeType="application/xml">
        </mulexml:xslt-transformer> 
    </flow>
```

and your xsl file `response.xsl` will be under resource folder as follows:-

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
        indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <xsl:for-each select="//client[position() &lt;= 4]">
             <client>
                <name>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name" />
                </name>
                <status>
                    <xsl:value-of select="status" />
                </status>
              </client>
            </xsl:for-each>
           </root>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

It will transform easily your input xml

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way: /root/client[position()<=4] as well.